# UIView.animation Issue

Tags: swift3, ios11, uianimation

UIView animation issue : after completing the animation there is an another animation which close slide up the view but leaving some line over the view how to resolve it?

[image]

```
let frameHeight: CGFloat = 44.0

self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -frameHeight, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: frameHeight)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            self.frame.origin.y += self.frameHeight

        }, completion: { _ in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, options: [], animations: {

                self.frame.origin.y -= self.frameHeight

            })

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the frame of the view before the animation begins because animation blocks don't run in the same runloop as the outer block context.

Moreover, i noticed you referred to `self.frameHeight` property in the animation blocks while you defined another `frameHeight` locally.

Try this (Precalculated origin Y):

```
let frameHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -frameHeight, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: frameHeight)

// Calcuate destinations before
let finalOriginDestinationY = self.frame.origin.y
let firstOriginDestinationY = self.frame.origin.y + frameHeight

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

    // Set absolute value - otherwise the frame is calculated according to position at current time
    self.frame.origin.y = firstOriginDestinationY
}, completion: { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, options: [], animations: {

        // Set absolute value (Precalculated)
        self.frame.origin.y = finalOriginDestinationY
    })

})
```